# python kivy ошибка с количеством аргументов при вызове метода

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет. Пишу приложением при помощи kivy. Есть две кнопки. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Создать группу" создавалось ещё одна кнопка в том же окне приложения. Определил метод, который создает ещё одну кнопку, но при нажатии выскакивает ошибка:

> TypeError: new_group() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда там два передаваемых аргумента и как пофиксить эту ошибку.

Код:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', size_hint = [None, None], size = [300,200])
        bl.add_widget( Button(text = "Создать группу", on_press = self.new_group))
        bl.add_widget( Button(text = "Мои группы"))
        al.add_widget(bl)
        return al

    def new_group(self):
        bl.add_widget( Button(text = "Новая группа"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю в чем твоя ошибка, я бы сделал так.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        al = AnchorLayout()
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical', size_hint = [None, None], size = [300,200])
        but1 = Button(text="Создать группу")

        bl.add_widget( but1)
        bl.add_widget( Button(text = "Мои группы"))
        al.add_widget(bl)


        def new_group(self):
            but2 = Button(text = "Новая группа")
            bl.add_widget(but2)

        but1.bind(on_release=new_group)

        return al
```